# Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

In some regex flavors, [negative] zero-width assertions (look-ahead/look-behind) are not supported.

This makes it extremely difficult (impossible?) to state an exclusion. For example "every line that *does not* have "foo" on it", like this:

```
^((?!foo).)*$
```

Can the same thing be achieved without using look-around at all (complexity and performance concerns set aside for the moment)?

Comment: Click the "regex-negation" tag to see some similar questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It fails "with two ff before oo" as [@Ciantic pointed out in the comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466053/regex-matching-by-exclusion-without-look-ahead-is-it-possible/466167#comment80765384_466167)

---

```
^(f(o[^o]|[^o])|[^f])*$
```

**NOTE:** It is much much easier just to negate a match on the client side instead of using the above regex.

The regex assumes that each line ends with a newline char if it is not then see C++'s and grep's regexs.

Sample programs in Perl, Python, C++, and `grep` all give the same output.

- [perl](http://ideone.com/90iZj)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -wn
  print if /^(f(o[^o]|[^o])|[^f])*$/;
  ```
- [python](http://ideone.com/3CYA6)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import fileinput, re, sys
  from itertools import ifilter

  re_not_foo = re.compile(r"^(f(o[^o]|[^o])|[^f])*$")
  for line in ifilter(re_not_foo.match, fileinput.input()):
      sys.stdout.write(line)
  ```
- c++

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <boost/regex.hpp>

  int main()
  {
    boost::regex re("^(f(o([^o]|$)|([^o]|$))|[^f])*$");
    //NOTE: "|$"s are there due to `getline()` strips newline char

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) 
      if (boost::regex_match(line, re))
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- [grep](http://ideone.com/kjO0J)

  ```
  $ grep "^\(f\(o\([^o]\|$\)\|\([^o]\|$\)\)\|[^f]\)*$" in.txt
  ```

Sample file:

```
foo
'foo'
abdfoode
abdfode
abdfde
abcde
f

fo
foo
fooo
ofooa
ofo
ofoo
```

Output:

```
abdfode
abdfde
abcde
f

fo
ofo
```

Comment: That's it. This is so simple that I'm ashamed not having thought of it myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's clear that post processing in the program, negating the match is the preferred method. Sometimes you don't have a choice, and even if you have, it is good to know your alternatives.

Comment: This regular expression is not correct. It does not match `f`, `fo` or `barf`. But this one does: `^(f(o([^o]|$)|[^o]|$)|[^f])*$`

Comment: @Gumbo: See regexps used for C++ and grep (hint: they are the same).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Ah, you’re right. I wonder why he didn’t change the other ones.

Comment: @Gumbo: I didn't change the other ones because the text in the answer clearly states: *The regex assumes that each line _ends with a newline char_ if it is not then see C++'s and grep's regexes.* Notice: *"ends with a newline"* and *"see C++'s regexp [otherwise]"*.

Comment: Answer does not seem to work with `somethingffoosomething` with two ff before oo.

Comment: @Ciantic: you are right e.g., both [perl](https://ideone.com/ZLPDkf) and [grep](https://ideone.com/NuyAl8) solutions shouldn't print anything (because both input lines have 'foo'). It just confirms the note at the top of the answer.

Comment: There is however a way to do this, if one could just figure out how! I try to find a negation for two chars first.

Comment: nice answer, but the fact that `foo` has 2 similar characters doesn't make the Q&A generic. It would be better with `abc`

Answer (score 5):

Came across this Question and took the fact that there wasn't a fully-working regex as a personal challenge. I believe I've managed to create a regex that *does* work for all inputs - provided you can use [atomic grouping](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)/[possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Of course, I'm not sure if there *are* any flavours that allow atomic grouping but not lookaround, but the Question asked if it's possible in regex to state an exclusion without lookaround, and it *is* technically possible:

```
\A(?:$|[^f]++|f++(?:[^o]|$)|(?:f++o)*+(?:[^o]|$))*\Z
```

Explanation:

```
\A                         #Start of string
(?:                        #Non-capturing group
    $                      #Consume end-of-line. We're not in foo-mode.
    |[^f]++                #Consume every non-'f'. We're not in foo-mode.
    |f++(?:[^o]|$)          #Enter foo-mode with an 'f'. Consume all 'f's, but only exit foo-mode if 'o' is not the next character. Thus, 'f' is valid but 'fo' is invalid.
    |(?:f++o)*+(?:[^o]|$)  #Enter foo-mode with an 'f'. Consume all 'f's, followed by a single 'o'. Repeat, since '(f+o)*' by itself cannot contain 'foo'. Only exit foo-mode if 'o' is not the next character following (f+o). Thus, 'fo' is valid but 'foo' is invalid.
)*                         #Repeat the non-capturing group
\Z                         #End of string. Note that this regex only works in flavours that can match $\Z
```

If, for whatever reason, you can use atomic grouping but not possessive quantifiers nor lookaround, you can use:

```
\A(?:$|(?>[^f]+)|(?>f+)(?:[^o]|$)|(?>(?:(?>f+)o)*)(?:[^o]|$))*\Z
```

As others point out, though, it's probably more practical to just negate a match through other means.

Comment: It's actually possible to express `^(?!.*foo)` without any extended regex features :D The solution in this case is: `^([^f]|(f+o)*f+([^fo]|o([^fo]|$)|$))*$`. We can even quite elegantly extend that to any arbitrary substring "foo"... I'll post a detailed write-up about this soon!

Comment: Reading these is made infinitely more complicated by the double 'oo' could someone who understands this please create one that does not contain that.

Comment: @Preston You want a non-lookaround regex to find, say, lines not containing "sna"? `\A(?:$|[^s]++|s++(?:[^n]|$)|(?:s++n)*+(?:[^a]|$))*\Z`

Comment: Is there  regex builder that would take a alphanumeric `string` and search lines NOT containing it (not using lookaround)?   What about adding additional words to the search?

Comment: @JonGrah I'd suggest making a new Question to ask that. The actual *practical* advice would likely be the same, though - if you can't use lookaround, then just write non-regex code to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question looking for my own regex exclusion solution, where I am trying to exclude a sequence *within* my regex.

My initial reaction to this situation:  *For example "every line that does not have "foo" on it"*  was simply to use the -v invert sense of matching option in grep.

```
grep -v foo
```

this returns all lines in a file that don't match 'foo'

It's so simple I have the strong feeling I've just misread your question....

Comment: `grep -v foo` searches for "foo" and negates the result, and the OP said he wanted the regex itself to do the work. But suppose the requirement were "contains 'foo' and *doesn't* contain 'bar'", and you could only perform one regex match? Simply negating the result wouldn't be an option then.

Comment: @Alan: True, but why the (seemingly) arbitrary one-regexp-match limit?  If we're not limited to one match, then we can pipeline: `grep foo <file> | grep -v bar`.  I bring this up because I could not figure out the examples above and make them work in Emacs, but was able to do just this on the command line.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung: Of course `grep -v` or equivalent is the best way to go, if available.  But the OP was talking about the hypothetical situation where you *can't* invert the match and you *can't* use lookaheads.  Fortunately, situations like that are extremely rare in the real world.  ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore extremely rare you say? Here's [one](https://busybox.net/BusyBox.html#find), and to think it's been 7 years since the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually look for foo and invert the result of the regex match from the client code.

For a simple example, let's say you want to validate that a string contains only certain characters.

You could write that like this:

`^[A-Za-z0-9.$-]*$`

and accept a `true` result as valid, or like this:

`[^A-Za-z0-9.$-]`

and accept a `false` result as valid.

Of course, this isn't always an option: sometimes you just have to put the expression in a config file or pass it to another program, for example.  But it's worth remembering. 
Your specific problem, for example, the expression is *much* simpler if you can use negation like this.

Comment: I know that post-processing would solve the problem... That's what I was trying to avoid, I was looking for a vanilla regex that does the right thing. Additionally, I am looking for something that disallows a specific sequence of characters, not an unordered set.