# Regular Expression to filter emails, numbers and repeated typings

Tags: java, regex, jsf, regex-negation

I am trying to validate an input in my JSF project and trying to create a regular expression to match any string which should not contain:

(1) strings such as @, com, yahoo, hotmail, gamil, googlemail

(2) any numbers

(3) a same letter repeating thrice or more

Comment: It is STRONGLY recommended that, when you ask a question, you also include what you have tried out before you couldn't take the frustration anymore and asked your question here :P

Comment: Is it a wrong think to keep the question "short and sweet"?

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
print "good" if $string !~ /@|com|yahoo|hotmail|gmail|googlemail|\d+|(\pL)\1\1/;
```

See also
[Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/466053/)

Comment: How can this be used? Where? Is this PHP code, or something else? DO enlighten us!! BTW, you spelt gmail as `gamil`

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: The question had tag `Perl` when I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that this is perl, and my first solution didn't work.

```
$str !~ /(@|(\w)\2\2|com|yahoo|gmail|hotmail|googlemail|\d)/
```

Since it's now tagged as jsf instead of perl, this is part of jsf core since 2.0:

```
 <f:validateRegex pattern="@|(\w)\1\1|com|yahoo|gmail|hotmail|googlemail|\d"/>
```

Put it inside the tag you want to validate

Comment: This is a plain copy of J. F. Sebastian's answer above. It does not explain anything. Stackoverflow, I believe, gives just as much importance to WHY a solution works as it does to DOES it work.

Comment: I didn't see any other answers when I posted that from my cell phone, and was going to add more info, but it was suddenly my turn at the hairdresser.

Comment: Sebastian beat you to it by 1 minute :)

Comment: Plagiarism it is then. Also, SO's intent is probably good, but the reputation system doesn't work all that well. Anyone can just post a half-assed solution, then bake other's solutions into their own and get it marked as the answer. Reputation extends your e-peen, and that's a good motivator. That's obviously not the case for 10k+ users, but you'll find a lot of them in the < 1000 segment.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b .
```

This regular expression, I claim, matches any email address

```
([0-9]*)
```

This is for any number .the scoop is for grouping.

FOR MORE INFO GO TO :
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

for testing online go to:
http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: .+@.+\.[a-z]+     for email see example :Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");