# Regex Adjacent Characters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to formulate a regex expression (running in Python) that gets passed a word and needs to only find words that do not contain 2 adjacent vowels. For Example:

```
me - would match
mee - would not match
meat - would not match
base - would match
basketball - would match
```

I am lost here as I do not know how to check for something that does not exist?

Thanks for the help

Comment: does it have to be regex? strings can act like lists, and so can be accessed as lists, you could feed a function a word and then parse it as a list, if two consecutive items are vowels, then it would fail, should i write this code for you?

Comment: related: [Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466053/4279)

Comment: @InbarRose yeah I would rather use regex for this. This is more of a learning thing than a real development project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = re.match(r"(?:[^euioa]|[euioa](?![euioa]))*$", word)
```

[@Tichodroma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934893/4279) is simpler and therefore should be preferable if you can negate the match in the code later i.e., just write `if not m` where you would write `if m` with this solution.

Comment: Should this be `"^(?:[^euioa]|[euioa](?![euioa]))*$"` ? (With the extra `^` at the beginning)

Comment: @Lee: re.search would need '^', re.match doesn't

Comment: You are right, I haven't read the deleted answer. Then you are correct and complete word needs to be checked (+1)

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

r = re.compile("[aeiou][aeiou]")
m = r.search("me")   # => None
m = r.search("mee")  # => Matcher
m = r.search("meat") # => Matcher
m = r.search("base") # => None
```

So `if not m` is `True` for all cases that don't match.

Comment: if m is not True probably looks nicer, and you might consider using that instead.

Comment: you should mention that it does the opposite i.e., it matches words that *do* contain adjacent vowels. It is a valid solution because It is simple to negate the match in the code later.

Comment: But Remember I am looking for the exact opposite of what you have done there. I am looking for the ones with adjacent vowels to not match