# Exclude a certain String from variable in regex

Tags: regex, xslt

Hi I have a Stylesheet where i use xsl:analyze-string with the following regex:

```
(&journal_abbrevs;)[\s&#160;]*([0-9]{{4}})[,][\s&#160;][S]?[\.]?[\s&#160;]?([0-9]{{1,4}})([\s&#160;][(][0-9]{{1,4}}[)])?
```

You don't need to look at the whole thing :)

&journal_abbrevs; looks like this:

```
"example-String1|example-String2|example-String3|..."
```

What I need to do know is exclude one of the strings in &journal_abbrevs; from this regex. E.g. I don't want example-String1 to be matched.

Any ideas on how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems XSLT regex does not support [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So I don't think you'll be able to get a solution for this that does not involve writing out all strings from `journal_abbrevs` in your regex. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466053/regex-matching-by-exclusion-without-look-ahead-is-it-possible).

To minimize the amount of writing out, you could split `journal_abbrevs` into say `journal_abbrevs1`, `journal_abbrevs2` and `journal_abbrevs3` (or how many you decide to use) and only write out whichever one that contains the string you wish to exclude. If `journal_abbrevs1` contains the string, you'd then end up with something like:

```
((&journal_abbrevs2;)|(&journal_abbrevs3;)|example-String2|example-String3|...)...
```

If it supported [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could've used a very simple:
`(?!example-String1)(&journal_abbrevs;)...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems that xslt does not support this. If I try (?!example-String1)(&journal_abbrevs;)[\s&#160;]*... the stylesheet can't be compiled anymore.

Comment: I had already thought of that but i hoped there was a more elegant solution. I guess I'll have to go with it.