# Python regex: find a substring that doesn't contain a substring

Tags: python, regex

Here is the example:

```
a = "one two three four five six one three four seven two"
m = re.search("one.*four", a)
```

What I want is to find the substring from "one" to "four" that doesn't contain the substring "two" in between.
The answer should be: m.group(0) = "one three four", m.start() = 28, m.end() = 41

Is there a way to do this with one search line?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this pattern:

```
one(?:(?!two).)*four
```

Before matching any additional character we check we are not starting to match "two".

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/yY2gG8

Comment: So we can use `(?:(?!two).)*` like it's a multi-character version of `^`, right?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this regexp reads "Between `one` and `four`, there should be zero or more group of characters that don't start with `two`."

Comment: @Satoru.Logic - That's right. Another option is `(?:[^t]|t[^w]|tw[^o])*`, which is compatible with regex flavors without  advanced features (lookahead).

Comment: In this case, I would happily go with `lookahead` ;)

Comment: @Kobi, `(?:[^t]|t[^w]|tw[^o])*` isn't quite right, because it can consume characters that *should* be matched by what follows. For example, `one(?:[^t]|t[^w]|tw[^o])*four` doesn't match `onetwfour` - the `f` in the string is consumed by `[^o]`.

Comment: @TimPeters - Excellent point. I can't think of a good solution except also disallowing `four`, which would be too messy. Lets stay with the lookahead, as Satoru suggested...

Comment: Agreed - your solution in the answer is by far the clearest of all :-)

Comment: @Kobi: related [Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/466053/4279)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)`:

```
re.findall("one(?!.*two).*four", a)
```

Comment: It works for his specific string, but not if you append " two" to his specific string - the lookahead applies to the *entire* remainder of the string, not just up until it finds the rightmost "four".

Comment: That's awesome!  It's awkward looking for some of these things.  I didn't even know how to properly search for an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2948379, note that Satoru edited your question to make it harder (added " two" to the end of your string), and the answer now doesn't find any matches (for the reason I explained in my comment above).  This is still harder than it looks ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I'm wondering if there is a simple way to check if a pattern is solvable using Regex ;p

Comment: @user2948379 Is it possible for a trailing `two` to occur in your inputs? If this is not the case, feel free to remove the `two` I added to your example and sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

With the harder string Satoru added, this works:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "one two three four five six one three four seven two"
>>> re.findall("one(?!.*two.*four).*four", a)
['one three four']
```

But - someday - you're really going to regret writing tricky regexps.  If this were a problem I needed to solve, I'd do it like this:

```
for m in re.finditer("one.*?four", a):
    if "two" not in m.group():
        break
```

It's tricky enough that I'm using a minimal match there (`.*?`).  Regexps can be a real pain :-(

EDIT:  LOL!  But the messier regexp at the top fails yet again if you make the string harder still:

```
a = "one two three four five six one three four seven two four"
```

FINALLY:  here's a correct solution:

```
>>> a = 'one two three four five six one three four seven two four'
>>> m = re.search("one([^t]|t(?!wo))*four", a)
>>> m.group()
'one three four'
>>> m.span()
(28, 42)
```

I know you said you wanted `m.end()` to be 41, but that was incorrect.

Comment: The second version - `one.*?four` with a filter - will fail for `"one two one five four"`. There *must* be an elegant solution that just captures `one` `four` and `two`, and takes the right pairs. Python should be a good language for such solutions, but I don't know it too well...

Answer (score 0):

another one liner with a very simple pattern

```
import re
line = "one two three four five six one three four seven two"

print [X for X in [a.split()[1:-1] for a in 
                     re.findall('one.*?four', line, re.DOTALL)] if 'two' not in X]
```

gives me

```
>>> 
[['three']]
```