# Folder exclusion in regex

Tags: regex, posix, pcre

I have to exclude a list of folders in a regular expression. Currently I am using a negative lookahead which works great:

- [`^(?!.*(?:google_csv|exclude_me_too)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qKlDle/1)

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm on a system that has `regex.h` as the only regex library installed which does not support a lookahead (as far as I'm aware). Is it possible to do the above pattern without a lookahead? I may have an arbitrary number of folders so I don't believe the technique described in [Regex: Matching by exclusion, without look-ahead - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466053/regex-matching-by-exclusion-without-look-ahead-is-it-possible). Is this possible to do without a lookahead? Or if not, I'll install something like `pcre2` to do the above.

Comment: You cannot match any string not containing a specific multichar sequence with a POSIX regex. Use `google_csv|exclude_me_too` and negate the result. Or install PCRE.

Comment: Why you don't try to match what you want to exclude and keep the remaining? In other words: *keep that if the pattern doesn't succeed.* It's very common to do that with a tool like grep for example.